# asp dropdownlist - add numbers 1-15 to list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way of adding the values 1-15 to an asp dropdownlist without having to do each one individually...

I currently have:

```
ddlAdults.Items.Insert(0, new listitem("1", "1"))
ddlAdults.Items.Insert(1, new listitem("2", "2"))
ddlAdults.Items.Insert(2, new listitem("3", "3"))
ddlAdults.Ite......
```

...etc but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 15
    ddlAdults.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()))
Next i
```

Answer (score 30):

```
ddlAdults.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 15)
ddlAdults.DataBind()
```

Comment: Note Enumerable.Range() is only supported in .NET 3.5 onwards

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
   ddlAdults.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem((i+1).toString(), (i+1).toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a  loop?

Like for loop or a foreach loop.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach

That should help u, as I dont know what language u're programming in..

Answer (score 0):

```
//cmbDay.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("1"));
//cmbDay.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("2"));
//cmbDay.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("3"));
//cmbDay.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("4"));

for( i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
       cmbDay.Items.Insert(i,new ListItem(i.ToString()));
    }
```