# Find information in datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable`. I need to fetch a certain columns from a `DataTable`. For example, lets say the `DataTable` has multiple columns and i want to retrieve two of them for example Id, Name

```
var item = new ListItem("k");
            item.Selected = true;
            this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
            item = new ListItem("n");
            this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
```

I want to replace the name to replace the k and n values and the data is in row 1 and 2, the names are for example steve and mike i want steve = k and mike =n, but i dont want to do the hard code the reference like below

```
var item = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(), dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
            item.Selected = true;
            this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
            item = new ListItem(dt.Rows[1][1].ToString(), dt.Rows[1][1].ToString());
            this.formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: What is this for a drop down?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Consider providing a worked example.

Comment: You don't want to hardcode the 0 and 1 of the datacolumn? Then use the datacolumn name.

Comment: the code is for a drop down and the the description has been given in the text above.

Comment: name of the column is "name" and the second column name is "id" and all i want is the the id and the column name data to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I understand correctly,* you need to **select** `Id and Name columns` and `filter rows using couple of given Ids` **from your datatable**.

```
int[] idList = new int[] { 11, 12 }; //Your Required Ids 

var results = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
               where idList.Contains(r.Field<int>("Id"))
               select new {Id = r.Field<int>("Id"),
                           Name = r.Field<string>("Name")}).ToList();

ddl.DataSource = results;
ddl.DataTextField = "Id";
ddl.DataValueField = "Name";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

```
// DataSource approach
formatOfReport.DataTextField = "Name";
formatOfReport.DataValueField = "Id";
formatOfReport.DataSource = dt;
formatOfReport.DataBind();

// programmatically
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int ID = row.Field<int>("Id");
    string name = row.Field<string>("Name");
    var item = new ListItem(name, ID.ToString());
    formatOfReport.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: this would create on fo each row in the table i only want a selection of row it 4-5 out of 100

Comment: You want only rows 4 and 5 based on the index of the row in the table?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like as you want bind DropDownList, you can do it like this

```
  DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
  DropDownList1.DataValueField="Id";
  DropDownList1.DataTextField="Name";
  DropDownList1.SelectedValue=//your Id
  DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813786/asp-dropdownlist-add-numbers-1-15-to-list post will be useful for you